# wix override ui banner causing artifacts

Tags: user-interface, wix, banner

I am trying to overrride the banner in my custom wix ui.

I have successfully done this using

The banner normally looks like this:
[image]

When I build the MSI and run it the banner is replaced but there are weird artifacts in it like this:
[image]
The edges seem to have gone all jagged (note the white up the top was me blanking out product name)

Is there a reason why the image goes like this and possible a way to avoid it?

Irfanview shows the following for the image properties:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the banner size in the MSI Wizard is different from the described default size of 500 × 63. You can use Paint to measure the banner. I've got 494 × 58 px on your screenshot. (I can't say the size of the banner bitmap we use at the moment, will add later.)

Note however: this size will work for default DPI setting of 96 dpi. If you choose 120 dpi or other settings, the size of the dialogs will grow, bitmap will be scaled and look jagged consequently. I do not know a workaround to this.

Comment: I'm confused IrFan view says the image is 500x63, are you saying I need to modify the DPI or something?

Comment: @Daniel Sorry if my answer was not clear enough. We use the banner bitmap with dimensions 492 × 58 for our MSI. As for DPI: when your display is set to 96 dpi, then the control in the MSI wizard that holds banner bitmap has size 493 × 58, you can use Spy++ to check this. If you or your users set display to 120 dpi or any other value, the size of the control will change, consequently the image will look jagged because it will be scaled to fit the new size.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could tell the original image was actually 500 x 63 (at least as reported by IrFanView and Paint)

I made a new image that was the size of 493 x 58 and DPI of 96 and this seems to have prevented the jaggies.

I looked at the Wix source and the UIExtension dialogs have the following line (or similar)

It looks like the image control is set to 370x44. I did try creating an image that size but still had problems.

Comment: The size of controls in WiX source is specified in **[Installer Units](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369490%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)**, not pixels.